# Is a question about sermon type allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

At my church, my pastor is quite adamant about a particular type of preaching. I'm well aware of alternative methods of preaching. It seems to me these methods are quite important; to the lay person as well as the pastor.

Can I ask a question about the biblical basis for a method of preaching?

E.g, "What is the biblical basis for the topical sermon series?"  or "What is the biblical basis for a lectio continua systematic expository sermon method?"

Obviously, as with all questions, I'd be asking an objective question (what is the biblical basis) not a subjective one (which is better).

Comment: You sure you're really only 17?  You ask questions I wish I could get seminary grads to ask!

Comment: @AffableGeek I have an awesome church and great teachers :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't narrow it to a biblical basis (What are the pros and cons of an expository sermon?) but you do want to keep it objective.

Comment: yeah, good point. I'll let this sit for a little, see if it attracts anymore attention. too tired to gather my thoughts to ask tonight anyways.